# Including OCR into Android Studio C++ project

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, tesseract

Using Android Studio, I have written an experimental app that runs OpenCV from within C++ code that is run natively via JNI. Everything that I tried in basic OpenCV works as expected.

Now I want to experiment with the "text" module from OpenCV Contrib. That is, the OCR / Tesseract module. For some reason, I don't get anywhere.

As I understand it there are several versions of this library. One called tess4j, another called tess-two and then opencv-contrib. The last one is the best choice?

Any pointers?

One nice person has made a sample, which I downloaded https://github.com/pethoalpar/AndroidOpenCvTesseractGetTextFromImage 
and it does build for me, but doesn't work when running it (on my phone S8+).

I get this:

```
05-27 17:15:26.371 411-411/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
05-27 17:15:26.372 411-411/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
05-27 17:15:26.373 411-411/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G955F_8.0.0_0002, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
05-27 17:15:26.374 411-411/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.pethoalpar.myapplication 
05-27 17:15:26.377 411-411/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-27 17:15:26.406 411-411/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
05-27 17:15:26.407 411-411/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
05-27 17:15:26.588 411-416/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
    After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
05-27 17:15:26.598 411-434/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from the current namespace instead.
05-27 17:15:26.601 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-27 17:15:26.622 411-434/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
05-27 17:15:26.765 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to get library list
05-27 17:15:26.774 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
05-27 17:15:26.774 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library list: ""
    First attempt to load libs
    Trying to init OpenCV libs
    Trying to load library opencv_java3
05-27 17:15:26.775 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Cannot load library "opencv_java3"
05-27 17:15:26.775 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.pethoalpar.myapplication-xdmsHX5km2PWImYxDfnyhQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"
05-27 17:15:26.776 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
        at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
        at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
        at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:91)
        at com.pethoalpar.myapplication.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1361)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3036)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
05-27 17:15:26.777 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
05-27 17:15:26.777 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs fails
05-27 17:15:26.777 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/MainActivity: OpenCv problem
05-27 17:15:26.790 411-416/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=37KB
    After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=37KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
05-27 17:15:26.797 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
05-27 17:15:26.802 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@c62b9d9[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
05-27 17:15:26.804 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Service connection created
05-27 17:15:26.807 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Trying to get library path
    Trying to get library list
    Library list: "libopencv_java3.so"
    First attempt to load libs
    Trying to init OpenCV libs
    Trying to load libs by dependency list
    Trying to load library /data/app/org.opencv.engine-1/lib/arm64/libopencv_java3.so
05-27 17:15:26.814 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: OpenCV libs init was ok!
    First attempt to load libs is OK
05-27 17:15:26.819 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper: General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.1 =====================================
      Version control:               3.3.1
05-27 17:15:26.820 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/OpenCVManager/Helper:   Platform:
        Timestamp:                   2017-10-24T14:00:34Z
        Host:                        Linux 4.8.0-58-generic x86_64
        Target:                      Linux 1 aarch64
        CMake:                       2.8.12.2
        CMake generator:             Ninja
        CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/ninja
        Configuration:               Release
      CPU/HW features:
        Baseline:                    NEON
          requested:                 NEON FP16
          required:                  NEON
          disabled:                  VFPV3
      C/C++:
        Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
        C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-g++ (ver 4.9)
        C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer   -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
        C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer   -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
        C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc
        C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer   -fvisibility=hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
        C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer   -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
        Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
        Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
        ccache:                      YES
        Precompiled headers:         NO
        Extra dependencies:          z dl m log
        3rdparty dependencies:       libcpufeatures libprotobuf libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf tegra_hal tbb
      OpenCV modules:
        To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect photo video dnn imgcodecs shape videoio highgui superres features2d calib3d java stitching videostab
        Disabled:                    js world
        Disabled by dependency:      -
        Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 python3 ts viz
      Android: 
        Android ABI:                 arm64-v8a
        STL type:                    gnustl_static
        Native API level:            android-21
        SDK target:                  android-21
        Android NDK:                 /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e (toolchain: aarch64-linux-android-4.9)
        android tool:                /opt/android/android-sdk-java7/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 25.2.2.)
        Google Play manager:         NO
        Android examples:            YES
      GUI: 
        GTK+:                        NO
        GThread :                    NO
        GtkGlExt:                    NO
        OpenGL support:              NO
        VTK support:                 NO
      Media I/O: 
        ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
        JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
        WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
        PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
        TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
        JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
        OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
        GDAL:                        NO
        GDCM:                        NO
      Video I/O:
      Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2018.0 interface 10001)
      Trace:                         YES ()
      Other third-party libraries:
        Use Intel IPP:               NO
        Use Intel IPP IW:            NO
        Use Eigen:                   NO
        Use Cuda:                    NO
        Use OpenCL:                  NO
        Use OpenVX:                  NO
        Use custom HAL:              YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
      Python 2:
        Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
      Python 3:
        Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
      Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
      Java:
        ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
        Java wrappers:               YES
        Java tests:                  NO
      Matlab:                        NO
      Tests and samples:
        Tests:                       NO
        Performance tests:           NO
        C/C++ Examples:              NO
      Install path:                  /build/master_pack-android/build/o4a/install
      cvconfig.h is in:              /build/master_pack-android/build/o4a
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
05-27 17:15:26.821 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Init finished with status 0
    Unbind from service
05-27 17:15:26.823 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenCVManager/Helper: Calling using callback
05-27 17:15:26.834 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
05-27 17:15:26.849 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
05-27 17:15:26.850 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 507596918784} changed=true
05-27 17:15:26.856 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-27 17:15:26.856 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
05-27 17:15:26.858 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.pethoalpar.myapplication
05-27 17:15:26.862 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2960]-format:1
05-27 17:15:26.862 411-436/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7640e13e50
05-27 17:15:26.922 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 192) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 192) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
05-27 17:15:26.926 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@9eee7aa nm : com.pethoalpar.myapplication ic=null
05-27 17:15:26.926 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
05-27 17:15:26.944 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@cca9f9b nm : com.pethoalpar.myapplication ic=null
05-27 17:15:30.789 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
05-27 17:15:30.837 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
05-27 17:15:30.852 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication E/MainActivity: file:///storage/emulated/0/Tess/imgs/ocr.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
05-27 17:15:31.221 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
05-27 17:15:31.271 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
05-27 17:15:31.282 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication E/MainActivity: file:///storage/emulated/0/Tess/imgs/ocr.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
05-27 17:15:31.535 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
05-27 17:15:31.627 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl@bd62c20[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
05-27 17:15:31.632 411-411/com.pethoalpar.myapplication E/MainActivity: file:///storage/emulated/0/Tess/imgs/ocr.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be many sets of instructions for this and as Android Studio, NDK and OpenCV changes the instructions may change which makes it very hard to follow. This article seems to be kept up to date, which is good - bear in mind that you may need to build separately for different processors: https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/building-opencv-for-android-from-source/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the instructions do not work for me. I got "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set." and after I made that error msg disappear, I got another, than another.

Perhaps because I have too modern Android Studio?

Comment: I never got it to work. I did solve the underlying problem though by throwing away OpenCV contrib and instead using Tesstwo.